# Can't cast date to a string formatted date in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I want to format the date object to a string date format - However, I get a cast error:

```
Cast to date failed for value "11/2020" at path "startdate"
```

The start date property is from type Date:

```
testSchema = new Mongoose.Schema({
   startdate: {
      type: Date
});
```

It's saved as type date in the collection - but later I need to get this object entry and change the startdate to a formatted string for further processing.

I tried it as following:

```
myObject.startdate = moment(myObject.startdate).format('MM/YYYY');
```

Then I get the cast error.

Is it even possible to achieve what I want? If no, how should I handle this then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just created a new array entry and wrote the formatted string into it. Couldn't find solution for the problem

Comment: Hi @micu have you found later the solution of your issue? I have a similar problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69153101/mongoose-updatemany-casting-date-to-string-type-returns-double-quoted-date-in

Comment: Hey @dev.doc. No, unfortunately not. I sticked to my solution explained above.